# Get the id of an input In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to to get in Jquery the id of the following input :

[image]

**The input is always in the second "td" and in the last "tr"

My try :

```
var LastDate = $("#content_tr").find('tr:last');
```

Afterward i don't know the correct syntax
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please read: [jQuery: traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var LastDate =  $("#content_tr tr:last td:eq(1) input").attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it returns "undefined"... :(

Comment: Then you'll need to post the actual HTML and not just an image. Please update your question with it. Also a jsFiddle helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var LastDate = $('tr>td>input.date','#content_tr').attr('id');
```

I guess you need to add .eq(X) to find the Xth element from the set of elements that jQuery returns, but it depends on your code and what exactly you want to get...

For example, to see all the ids you get:

```
$('tr>td>input.date','#content_tr').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it returns "undefined"... :(

Comment: Can you make a sample in jsFiddle so we can be sure we talk for the same code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to pull out a specific element in the list of matching elements.

In this case I'd do:

```
$('#content_tr tr:last td').get(1);
```